# How do I use jQuery to use the hyperlink text as a variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, attributes, selector, href

I've got a jQuery function that is going to replace each hyperlink with a jPlayer using that hyperlink as its source. The hyperlink looks like this in HTML:

```
<div>
<a href="demos/myfile.mp3" rel = 'jPlayer'>myfile</a>
</div>
```

So what I've got so far in my Javascript is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $('a[rel="jPlayer"]').jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: $(this).attr("href") });
});
```

The problem is I can't figure out the right selector to take the value of the existing hyperlink and use it for the mp3: source in the code. Maybe I'm not even using $this right, or maybe it's something completely different that I'm missing.

When I run the code as is, I get "a.attributes is null" in Firebug. Can anyone help fix this up?

Comment: In some mobile browsers which are faster because they send the data optimiyed to the phone or device, there is a problem with $(this) in that it has to reload the page. Dont use it unless you actually have to. In this case, you dont need it. The first answer below is a better solution. You can even have $('a[rel="jPlayer"]').click(function(){}); and assign the clicked item to a variable.

Comment: There's still something wrong with it, I'm trying it in a super-simple HTML file as above with proper script srcs but the link doesn't change to the player, it just stays as a link. I've tried all three functions below and they don't throw errors (so I know they all work as intended) but there's still something wrong. Maybe I can't use it on a hyperlink?

Comment: MAy have to do with the order you call the js files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is with your script construction:

```
$('a[rel="jPlayer"]').jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: $(this).attr("href") });
```

You are referrring with this to jPlayer, not selected value. You should use it in other way, try this:

```
$('a[rel="jPlayer"]').jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: $('a[rel="jPlayer"]').attr("href") });
```

or eaven

```
var anchor = $('a[rel="jPlayer"]');
anchor.jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: anchor.attr("href") });
```

Comment: This was the closest to my original code so it made the most sense to me, and seems to work just as well as the later answers so I'll choose this answer. Unfortunately I have other issues with this jPlayer and I think I'm going to dump it in favor of simpler interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

There can be more than one link on the page. To correctly initialize each jPlayer instance you can iterate over all links and initialize jPlayer for each matched element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('a[rel="jPlayer"]').each(function(index){
        var link = $(this);
        link.jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: link.attr("href") });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `this` isn't working in an obvious manner, I'd pull out the selector and re-use it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  var media_link = $('a[rel=jPlayer]');
  media_link.jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: media_link.attr("href") });
});
```

This has the dual effect of only calling `extend` on the anchor element once rather than twice. I changed the selector slightly by removing the quote marks.